# Adding value to a sub child in core data swift ios

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have tried a lot and researched a lot but never found an answer to this question or similar tutorial, I have the firebase like database, see the following tree. How can I store the data into a sub child like this in `Core data`

[image]

What I want Similar to above is

```
 Model->Form 
        |
        --> Model-FormElements
        |         |
        |         -->TextField
        |                |
        |                --> textField1
        |                --> textField2
        |                --> textFiedl3
        --> Model-FormData
        |         |
        |         -->TextFieldName
        |                |
        |                --> FullName
        |                --> Email
        |                --> City
```

Then I want to create different types of forms some have buttons and titles or labels and titles

What I have done so far is I am inserting objects into new entities instead of child of an entity:

```
  @IBAction func saveAction(_ sender: Any) {

        let appDel:AppDelegate = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate)
        let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let formDataEntity = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "FormElements", into: context) as NSManagedObject

        formDataEntity.setValue(textFieldElement, forKey: "textField")
        formDataEntity.setValue(buttonElement, forKey: "button")
        formDataEntity.setValue(labelElement, forKey: "label")
        formDataEntity.setValue(sectionElement, forKey: "section")
        formDataEntity.setValue(dateElement, forKey: "date")
        formDataEntity.setValue(textViewElement, forKey: "textView")
        formDataEntity.setValue(textViewNameElement, forKey: "textViewName")
        formDataEntity.setValue(signViewElement, forKey: "signView")
        formDataEntity.setValue(signViewNameElement, forKey: "signViewName")
        formDataEntity.setValue(imageElement, forKey: "imageView")
        formDataEntity.setValue(imageNameLabelElement, forKey: "imageViewName")
        formDataEntity.setValue(checkBoxElement, forKey: "checkBox")
        formDataEntity.setValue(spaceElement, forKey: "space")


        //extra formData saving of names to elements
        let formDataNameEntity = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "FormData", into: context) as NSManagedObject

        formDataNameEntity.setValue(textFieldNameFD, forKey: "textFieldD")
        formDataNameEntity.setValue(buttonNameFD, forKey: "buttonD")
        formDataNameEntity.setValue(labelNameFD, forKey: "labelD")
        formDataNameEntity.setValue(sectionNameFD, forKey: "sectionD")
        formDataNameEntity.setValue(dateNameFD, forKey: "dateD")
        formDataNameEntity.setValue(textViewNameFD, forKey: "textViewNameD")
        formDataNameEntity.setValue(signViewNameFD, forKey: "signViewNameD")
        formDataNameEntity.setValue(imageNameLabelFD, forKey: "imageViewNameD")


        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch {}

 }
```

Comment: Are you asking how you model your data in core-data?  If so you should should explain what real life objects you are trying to model.

Comment: above model objects are real objects

Comment: But I have dynamic objects as well like an element and hiss name

Comment: What does your app do?

Comment: @JonRose it creates forms

Answer (score 0):

You can't use core data like firebase.
Firebase is NoSql database, where coredata is not. So in order to achieve your goal to use core data like firebase service, you can make multiple entities and manage relation between them.

Comment: But I cant manage their relationship and how can I make core data multiple entities like this firebase structure

Comment: Sorry but you can’t.

Comment: any alternate to this solution

Comment: Use any nosql database

Comment: name some NoSQL databases please